# Errors when installing Plesk: Depends: libodbc1 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed

Tags: dependencies, php7

I'm trying to install Plesk, and get the following error messages:

```
 plesk-librdbmspp : Depends: libodbc1 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
 plesk-php72-odbc : Depends: libodbc1 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
 plesk-php73-odbc : Depends: libodbc1 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
 plesk-php74-odbc : Depends: libodbc1 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
 plesk-php80-odbc : Depends: libodbc1 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
```

When I ran the following, it said version 2.3.6 was already installed:

```
apt-get install libodbc1:i386
```

I (newbie) understand the error to mean that it needs libodbc1 version 2.3.1 or greater, and therefore my version (2.3.6) should work. What can I do to fix those errors, and install Plesk?

Comment: Are you using a 32-bit version of Ubuntu?

Comment: lol, no. Thanks you were right. I wasn't using the 64-bit version. Please post your answer. Thank you sooo much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that `i386` bit is your problem. This might work better:

```
apt-get install libodbc1
```

Generally we don't need to specify a platform when installing software unless there is a *very* specific need to do so.